# Problems with handing information from a c++ cgi-script to a javascript-tag

Tags: javascript, c++, web-applications, cgi

I try to set a variable for a javascript function with my cgi script hosted on the local IIS(Win7):

cgi:

```
cout<<"Content-type: text/javascript\r\n\r\n";
cout<<"var value=2;";
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./cgi-bin/value.exe"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write('The number is: ' + value);
-->
</script>
```

But when i open the html file with the js-code document.write does nothing. And when i analyse the page with firebug a lot of weird characters inside the js-tag and somewhere in the middle of these characters there is my output: "var value=2".

Has anybody an idea what is going on?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: here a snippet from what firebug tells me is between the script tags:

```
MZ�������ÿÿ��¸�������@�����

)��")��4)��F)��\)��p)��z)��)��)��)��¬)��Æ)
��Ø)��)��ô(��Ê(��¼  (��°(��¤(��(��(��(�
(��l(��^(��<(��à(����������@���������È@�û��
������bad allocation��Content-type: text/javascript
���var NumberOfFiles = 2; 

?�������������0���������������� ��H���
X@��V��ä������<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
manifestVersion="1.0">
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<security>
<requestedPrivileges>
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
</requestedPrivileges>
</security>
</trustInfo>
<dependency>
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC90.CRT" 
version="9.0.21022.8" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b">
</assemblyIdentity>
</dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
/assembly>PAPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDING
XXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADD���0�������
```

Can anyone tell where this output is coming from?

Comment: its the "<!--" left intentionally or you forgot to comment it out like the other?

Comment: The other one should not be commented out. This comment is only for browser that have javascript deactivated. It was a copy&paste error, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Also, was it your intention to leave open quotes around **./cgi-bin/value.exe** ?

Comment: So few lines of code and 2 mistakes so far, sorry for that! But i still get the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to just fine here. Naturally, you gotta run it from localhost (or some other server)

**testCgi.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cgi-bin/cgiBinNum.cgi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('The number is: ' + value);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**cgiBinNum.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Content-type: text/javascript\r\n\r\n";
    cout<<"var value=2;";
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/cgi-bin/cgiBinNum.cgi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write('The number is: ' + value);
</script></head><body>The number is: 2




</body></html>
```

Yeah, the 'MZ' gives it away instantly - Mark Zbikowski.

Basically, it's actually serving up the exe file itself, not just the result of it.

If you open the file in a hex-editor, it will look remarkably similar.

When you say, that's 'pretty-much' what you've got, the devil is always in the details.

Got any more of them?

I've 2 suggestions - 
(1) provide the smallest *full* source that replicates your problem, as I have done 
(2) change the file extension to .cgi and alter the javascript to reflect this. (You should also get into the habit of adding another build-target to the project and set it's output folder to your cgi-bin folder, also the extension to cgi, rather than exe) This shouldn't make a difference to this problem, but it is better in general not to have easily executable files in that folder - easily, as in you can double-click them and they will run, you can always run from the command line if you use a full path, as apache does.

Ahhh! Just realized you're using IIS - I think you find that it's that b@stard of a thing that's messing up your output. Probably makes point (1) moot - It's sounding more likely to me that it will be a IIS setting - though it could also be serving the contents of the file, rather than the output - simply based on it's extension. Give it a try!

Comment: That's pretty much what I've got. But it is good to now that it should work like this...   I edited my post to show you the output i get, maybe you know where it could come from?

Comment: My comment is too large. See my updated answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank You! It was a IIS Setting. I have to add a script handler for the .exe-file otherwise it just returns the file.

Comment: @Sammy46 - you're most welcome. Good info to have, cheers. :)